# How to have one thread listen for data while main thread is doing some operation

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to create a one thread to listen for incoming data from COM serial port while main thread is doing some operation.

Here is my code (some codes are omitted for brevity) :

```
def readMsg( serial ):
    msgArray = []
    while ( True ):
        char = "0x" + serial.read().encode('hex')
        if char == '0xfd':
            msgArray = []
            msgArray.append(char)
        elif char == '0xfc':
            msgArray.append(char)
            print debugPrefix, "ComPort:", (serial.port + 1), msgArray
        elif char == '0x':
            pass
        else:
            msgArray.append(char)


# Find available ports                  
initializeComPorts() 

# Print port infos
printComPorts() 

# Opens serial and returns opened serial
serialPort = openPort(1);

print "thread started"
readMsgThread = threading.Thread( target=readMsg(serialPort) )
readMsgThread.setDaemon( True )
readMsgThread.start()

print "sending some data"
serialPort.send('h')
```

When I execute the code `readMsgThread` listens fine, but the line `print "sending some data"` is never executed. Can someone please explain what am I missing? I've been stuck at this for a while.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Be careful with the `while True:` loop. It may take 100% of a CPU core. Replace `pass` with `time.sleep`.

Comment: @Igonato, presumably `serial.read()` blocks until data on the port is available.  In which case sleeping isn't appropriate.  But, yup, otherwise yes ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't test this for you, but think carefully about this line:

```
readMsgThread = threading.Thread( target=readMsg(serialPort) )
```

That **calls** `readMsg(serialPort)` at the time the assignment is excecuted, and passes the result as `target`.  I'm guessing you almost certainly want to do:

```
readMsgThread = threading.Thread( target=readMsg, args=(serialPort,) )
```

instead.

To clarify a little more, because you're **calling** `readMsg` on that line, no further lines will be executed until `readMsg` returns.  But that function never returns.  That's why "sending some data" is never seen.  In fact, you never get to the

```
readMsgThread.setDaemon( True )
```

statement either.